# Добавление записи в таблицу mysql

Tags: javafx, hibernate

Делаю проект баз данных. Использую Hibernate. С реализацией отображения и удаления данных из таблицы проблем нету.
 А вот с добавление новой записи никак.
 Возможно ли реализовать метод добавление новой записи в таблицу через дополнительную форму с textField-ами для ввода информации?
 Метод удаления:

```
private void delete(Integer idorders) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        OrdersEntity ordersEntity = session.get(OrdersEntity.class, idorders);
        session.delete(ordersEntity);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
```

Вот метод кнопки на добавление:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query1 = session.createSQLQuery("INSERT INTO orders" +
            "(date, descrip_orders, idclients, idmasters, idworks, note, idstatus)" +
            "VALUES " +
            "(tFDate.getValue().toString(), tfDescrip.getText(), tfClients.getText(), tFMasters.getText(), tfWorks.getText()," +
            "tfNote.getText(), tfStatus.getText())");
    query1.executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Succsess!");
```

Значения требуется получать из textField-ов. При использовании в запросе строк всё вроде бы работает. Но никак не получается с переменными и textField.

Comment: Напишите код добавления и где вы его используете

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вам нужен ORM, если вы всё равно используете SQL? Можно же просто инстанцировать сущность, установить её свойства и сохранить:

```
OrdersEntity order = new OrdersEntity();
order.setDate(tFDate.getValue().toString());
...
session.beginTransaction();
session.persist(order);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Но если всё-таки хочется использовать SQL по какой-то причине, то параметры запроса надо устанавливать иначе:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO orders"
             + "(date, descrip_orders, idclients, idmasters, idworks, note, idstatus)"
             + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
Query query = session.createNativeQuery(sql);
query.setParameter(1, tFDate.getValue().toString());
...
session.beginTransaction();
query.executeUpdate();
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

И лучше бы поменять тип полю `date` со строкового на дату, а имена полей привести в соответствие с принятыми стилевыми нормами. Как, впрочем, и имя класса сущности.